# How to find an argument of $ z=1-\cos\varphi-i\sin\varphi $?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> How to find an argument of this complex number?
>   $$
> z=1-e^{i\varphi}=1-\cos\varphi-i\sin\varphi
> $$

I know I should try to make $z$ equal to $r(\cos\psi+i\sin\psi)$. And then $Arg(z)=\psi$. But I don't really understand how to do that.
I tried something like that:
$$
z=2\sin^2\frac{\varphi}{2}-2i\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}=2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\left(\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}-i\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)
$$
But obviously it didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track:

\begin{align*}
z&=2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\left(\sin \frac{\varphi}{2}-i\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\\
&=2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\left(-ie^{i\varphi/2}\right)\\
&=2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}\left(e^{-i\pi/2}e^{i\varphi/2}\right)\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}

Comment: But $2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$ can't be $r$, since it is not constant. Am I wrong?

Comment: I mean $2\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$ is not a modulus. It can be negative.

Comment: But it's always real. So you only have two cases to consider depending on its sign.

Comment: ...actually, this question is basically a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754497/finding-the-argument-of-z-1-cos2-theta-i-sin2-theta?rq=1

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out to me.